# php/jquery - Print values from PHP array with second delay for each

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have an array generated serverside using php eg. `array("one", "two", "three")` and want to show the results on a page.

Instead of just looping through and printing them, I want to delay printing each one by a second using jquery.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    // how do i grab and show php array value?
    $('#log').append(ARRAY VALUE); 
    }, 1000);

<span id=log></span>
```

Tried searching but couldn't figure out a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you get the array :)

But you can do this:

php

```
<?php
    $array = [1, 2, 3];
```

html

```
<span class="hidden" id="phpArr" data-values="<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>"></span>
```

js

```
var array = $('#phpArr').data('values');
array = $.parseJSON(array);

array.each(function(i, v)
{
    setTimeout(function() {$('#div').append(i)}, 1000)
})
```

what this does is looop through the array and append it to a div with id of div with a second delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply  use like below also.

```
<div id="log" style="display:none">
// Generate your output with php code
</div>
```

inside document.ready display after n seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#log').show(); 
    }, 1000);
});
```

Let me know if it not works

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code.

Php code:

```
<?php 
    $_temparray = ["one", "two", "three"];
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<span id=log></span>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>

    var temp_data= '<?php echo implode(",",$_temparray); ?>';
    var split_data = temp_data.split(',');
    for(var i=0;i<split_data.length;i++){
            displayMessage(split_data[i]);
    }
    function displayMessage(val){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#log').append(val);
            //console.log(val);
        },1000);
    }
</script>
```

> This thing is not logically possible. Generally this is not advice
>   able to mix **PHP** and **javascript** code.